# SQL 2nd Case Statement Off First Case Statement's Column

Tags: sql, case-when

I am writing a query with two Case When statements, the 2nd using the status of the first to determine the value. However, I am getting an invalid column error on the 2nd statement. Does anyone know an easy solution to fix this? Thanks!

```
select 
    a.ID
    ,ss.Date
    ,ss.Name
    ,ss.Payload
    ,case when statusdescription = 'Bad Request' then 'Not Resolved' Else 'Resolved' End as [Error Status] 
    ,case when 
    [Error Status] = 'Not Resolved' --Invalid Column issue occurring with [Error Status] here
    then 'No Resolution' Else a.Date End as [Date],
    ,GETDATE() [Insert Date]

from #Errors a
join Table1 ss on a.id = ss.Id and a.Date = ss.Date 
order by a.Date desc
```

Comment: Case _expressions_, not _statements_...

Comment: I just did a test of my own (Sql Server 2014) and I was able to reference a preceding CASE column from a subsequent one so it is possible (in SQL Server 2014).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would nest the first case expression in the second case expression.

```
select 
a.ID
,ss.Date
,ss.Name
,ss.Payload
,case when statusdescription = 'Bad Request' then 'Not Resolved' Else 'Resolved' End as [Error Status] 
,case when 
case when statusdescription = 'Bad Request' then 'Not Resolved' Else 'Resolved' End = 'Not Resolved' --Invalid Column issue occurring with [Error Status] here
then 'No Resolution' Else a.Date End as [Date],
,GETDATE() [Insert Date]

from #Errors a
join Table1 ss on a.id = ss.Id and a.Date = ss.Date 
order by a.Date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second `CASE` expression, you can just check the value of `statusdescription` again:

```
SELECT 
    a.ID,
    ss.Date,
    ss.Name,
    ss.Payload,
    CASE WHEN statusdescription = 'Bad Request'
         THEN 'Not Resolved' ELSE 'Resolved' END AS [Error Status], 
    CASE WHEN statusdescription = 'Bad Request'
         THEN 'No Resolution' ELSE a.Date END AS [Date],
    GETDATE() AS [Insert Date]
FROM #Errors a
INNER JOIN Table1 ss
    ON a.id   = ss.Id   AND
       a.Date = ss.Date 
ORDER BY a.Date DESC
```

Note that if this query does not run, you might have to convert `a.Date` to text inside your second `CASE` expression.